# Finding $E(X(X-1))$ where $X$ is a Poisson random variable such that $P(X=2) = \frac{2}{3} P(X=1)$

Tags: probability, expectation, poisson-distribution

> Let $X$ be a Poisson random variable such that $P(X = 2) = \frac{2}{3} P (X = 1)$. Find $E(X(X − 1))$.

I know $E(X(X-1)) = E(X^2) - E(X)$, but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: If this question comes from some source (_e.g._, a textbook) it would be preferable to appropriately cite the source.

Answer (score 3):

First we find the parameter $\lambda$ of the Poisson. We have $\Pr(X=2)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^2}{2!}$ and $\Pr(X=1)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda}{1!}$. From the given equation we conclude that $\frac{\lambda^2}{2}=\frac{2}{3}\lambda$, so now we know $\lambda$, since it cannot be $0$.

The expectation of $X(X-1)$ is equal to
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1)e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}.$$
The first two terms are $0$, and for $k\ge 2$ we have $\frac{k(k-1)}{k!}=\frac{1}{(k-2)!}$, so our sum is
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{(k-2)!}.$$
Replace $k-2$ by $n$. Our sum is
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{n+2}}{n!}.$$
Bring out a $\lambda^2$. We end up with
$$\lambda^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{n}}{n!}.$$
But the sum after the $\lambda^2$ is $1$, for it is the sum of all the Poisson probabilities. We conclude that $E(X(X-1))=\lambda^2$.

**Remark:** In a similar way, we could compute $E(X(X-1)(X-2))$, and other similar expressions. This sort of expectation  is easier to get at than things like $E(X^2)$ and $E(X^3)$. In fact, finding the expectation of $X(X-1)$ is one of the standard paths for finding the variance of $X$.

Answer (score 2):

From the identity
\begin{equation}
\text{Var}(X) = E(X^2) - (E(X))^2
\end{equation}
you can get
\begin{equation}
E(X^2) = \text{Var}(X) + (E(X))^2
\end{equation}
remember that $E(X)$ is just the mean, and the varriance of a poisson distribution is the same as the mean($E(X) = \text{Var(X)})$. This yields the final equation
\begin{equation}
E(X(X - 1)) = E(X^2) - E(X) = E(X) + (E(X))^2 - E(X) = (E(X))^2
\end{equation}
So from your first equation solve for the mean. Your answer will be the square of your mean.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda}} 2 = \Pr(X = 2) = \frac 2 3 \Pr(X = 1) = \frac 2 3 \cdot \frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda}}{1}.
$$
Multiplying both sides by $6e^\lambda/\lambda$, we get
$$
3\lambda = 4
$$
so $\lambda = 4/3$.

So
$$
\operatorname{E}(X(X-1)) = \operatorname{E}(X^2) - \operatorname{E}(X) = \Big( (\operatorname{E} X)^2 + \operatorname{var}(X) \Big) - \lambda = (\lambda^2 + \lambda) - \lambda = \lambda^2 = \frac{16} 9.
$$